# How to remove all circles in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

How do I remove all the grey circles at once in Inkscape? Please see attached image. I can manually select one Object at a time and delete.

I am very confused with using the eraser tool

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inkscape has several options to "select all same". Select one circle and try for ex. Edit > Select same > Fill color and press DEL. Before pressing DEL deselect all unwantedly selected grey parts. Click them holding Shift at the same time. You can also lock other same colored shapes in the Objects panel.